# how does one get past this error when compiling a .py file into a .exe with auto-py-to-exe (py-installer)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

> pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (six 1.12.0 (c:\users\welcome\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('six>=1.13.0'), {'google-api-core'})

I've tried updating six, uninstalling it and reinstalling, downgrading google-api-core, and moving up to date versions directly into the directory, is there any fix to this that I've missed?

any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: try installing pybigquery==0.4.13 six==1.14.0

Comment: @KenLee somehow that fixed everything, including some other issues, thanks!

Comment: Great to know that you fixed the problem. Have a nice day

Comment: @KenLee thanks, you too! :)